# bottom up mergesort

Tags: c++, mergesort

i have following code for bottom up mergesort it does it's  operation on file   m-by-m merges  doubles m on each pass  here is code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

inline int Min(int a,int b)
{
    return a<b?a:b;
}

void merge(int a[],int l,int m,int r)
{
    vector<int>b;
    int i, j;
    for (i=m+1;i>=l;i--)  b[i-1]=a[i-1];
    for (j=m;j<r;j++) b[r+m-j]=a[j+1];
    for (int k=l;k<=r;k++)
        if ( b[j]<b[i]) 
            a[k]=b[j--];  
        else
            a[k]=b[i++];
}

void mergesort(int a[],int l,int r)
{
    for (int m=1;m<=r-l;m=m+m)
        for (int i=l;i<=r-m;i+=m+m)
            merge(a,i,i+m-1,Min(i+m+m-1,r));
}

int main()
{
    int a[]={12,4,7,3,9,8,10,11,6};
    int n=sizeof(a)/sizeof(int);
    mergesort(a,0,n-1);
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cout<<a[i]<< "  ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

but when i run this code   there is exception which says that vector's out of range error was occured please help

Comment: What line does the exception come from?  What element were you attempting to access, and how big do you believe the vector to be?  How deep is your callstack at that point?  Was the index out of range, i, j, or k?

Honestly, @user466441, most of your questions are "here's a bunch of code, please help", with no information or effort from you.

Comment: I reformatted your code for you.  However, more consistent formatting still doesn't fix your poor variable names, inconsistent use of brackets and single-line for statements.

Answer (score 2):

You have not initialised your vector to have any data in it.

I guess this is an exercise which is why you are reinventing the wheel. I am not sure that is an excuse for using single-character identifiers which makes your code hard to understand.

If a is an array and l is its length you can initialise b with

```
vector<int> b( a, a+l );
```

Presumably you are creating a temporary clone of your array for the purpose of the sort.

Isn't mergesort recursive, by the way? I don't see yours being.

I have other issues with your code too, eg your indentation suggests that the for loops are nested but the semi-colons after the statements that are on the same line as the for statements suggest otherwise. I'd suggest you always use braces on your loops.

Comment: That's what "bottom-up" implies: it's loop recursive instead of call-recursive.

Answer (score 2):

In function `merge` you have `vector<int>b;` b is of size 0 here. You should `rezise()` your vector, or initialize it with the array:

```
vector<int> v(arr, arr+size);
```

Answer (score 1):

You create `b` as an empty vector, and then start addressing its elements. It has size 0, so that's invalid. You should give it a larger size.

Answer (score 1):

Others have addressed your problem with trying to index elements in an empty vector. In addition, the following loop has a problem:

```
for (i=m+1;i>=l;i--)  b[i-1]=a[i-1];
```

The last iteration through the loop has `i=l` and you address the `[i-1]` element of the vector/array. When `l=0` this is the index `-1` and will be out-of-range for both the vector and array.